# Partitive genitive in Spinoza

Tags: grammar-identification, spinoza, ethica, partitive-genitive

Spinoza, Ethics, De Deo, Propositio 15, Scholium:

> Sane **rerum**  quae realiter ab invicem  distinctae sunt, una sine alia esse et in suo statu manere potest

Is **rerum** *partitive genitive* and is it correct to rearrange the sentence in this manner?

> Sane *una* **rerum**  quae realiter ab invicem  distinctae sunt, sine alia esse et in suo statu manere potest

Otherwise, which type of genitive corresponds to **rerum**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this does indeed appear to be a partitive genitive.
Changing the word order as you suggest is legitimate if it helps you.
I think it is most useful in its original place where *una* and *sine alia* are next to each other.

I like analyzing things sequentially, so let us start with the whole sentence.
To clarify the role of the relative clause, I will add another comma:

> Sane rerum, quae realiter ab invicem distinctae sunt, una sine alia esse et in suo statu manere potest.

To better grasp the core message, we can ignore the relative clause which gives additional detail:

> Sane rerum una sine alia esse et in suo statu manere potest.

Let me also drop the other half of what can be done:

> Sane rerum una sine alia esse potest.

Now the message is clear:

> Clearly one of the things can exist without another.

If there are only two things, then "the other" is better than "another".

Comment: I don't think this is what the "una" is doing here. He seems to be saying, "Of things that are really distinct from each other, one can exist without the other." In other words, I'm reading it like a more typical "alius...alius" construction.

Comment: @brianpck Hmm... To me that seems to be a detail of phrasing it in English, but I might be somewhat misled by it being a second language. It gets a little mangled after my simplifications and I did not read around the quoted passage at all, so my translation is certainly sub-optimal. But I hope I at least got the role of *rerum* clear enough.